# get text from entry box and insert in email python

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a entry box with information.

```
debnmr_tekst=StringVar()
debnmr=Entry(f2,bd=3,textvariable=debnmr_tekst)
debnmr.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor=CENTER)
```

I like to past that information behind debiteur: in the msg var.

try'd to use the get() function but i get an error. Hope you guys can help me out!:)

```
def mail_2():
    username = "****@gmail.com"
    password = ("*********")
    recipient = "********@hotmail.com"
    msg = ("""subject: Zending is afgehaald!

    Onderstaande zending is afgehaald.

    Debiteur:debnmr_tekst.get()
    Klant:
    Aantal pallets:
    Totaal gewicht:
    PB nummers:

    *Dit bericht is automatisch gegenereerd
    """)


    server = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com",587)
    server.starttls()
    server.login(username, password)

    server.sendmail(username,recipient, msg)
    server.quit()
```

Comment: Would you tell us, what the error is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use string formatting to include variables into a string.

```
msg = ("""subject: Zending is afgehaald!

Onderstaande zending is afgehaald.

Debiteur:{}
Klant:
Aantal pallets:
Totaal gewicht:
PB nummers:

*Dit bericht is automatisch gegenereerd
""")
msg = msg.format(debnmr_tekst.get())
```